# SQL Server : default constraint doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a small problem with my code. I added a default constraint but for some reason it doesn't want to work. My code:

```
CREATE TABLE oc.students 
(
    stud_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    mid_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DOB DATE,
    email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(20),
    reg_date DATE NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE oc.students
ADD DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [reg_date];

INSERT INTO oc.students (first_name, mid_name, last_name, DOB, email, country, phone, reg_date)
VALUES ('John', '', 'Smith', '1986-12-24', 'js@gmail.com', 'Malta', 123456789, '')

SELECT * 
FROM oc.students
```

Result:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`''` and `NULL` are not the same (well, in any database other than Oracle).  The first is a string that happens to have no characters.  The second is a SQL constant value that has the semantics of "unknown value" and is often used for missing values.

You are inserting `''` which is interpreted as `0`, which gets converted to the base date.  Actually, the technical term for this is *epoch*, which is the date a uses to start counting date/time values.

If you want the default, you can use:

```
VALUES (
    'John',
    '',
    'Smith',
    '1986-12-24',
    'js@gmail.com',
    'Malta',
    123456789,
    DEFAULT
    )
```

Or, more commonly, the column is just left out:

```
INSERT INTO oc.students (
                    first_name,
                    mid_name,
                    last_name,
                    DOB,
                    email,
                    country,
                    phone)
VALUES (
    'John',
    '',
    'Smith',
    '1986-12-24',
    'js@gmail.com',
    'Malta',
    123456789
    )
```